# Why does "const auto [x, y]" not behave as expected when binding to reference types?

Tags: c++, standards, c++17, decltype, structured-bindings

The following code snippet is excerpted from [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

```
std::tuple<int, int&> f();

auto [x, y] = f(); 
// decltype(x) is int
// decltype(y) is int&

const auto [z, w] = f();
// decltype(z) is const int
// decltype(w) is int&
```

My question is at the last line:

**Why** **is** `decltype(w)`  `int&` **rather than** `const int&`**?**

Comment: with `const`, you would have "`int & const`" which is `int&`.

Comment: Because `std::tuple_element<1, const std::tuple<int, int&>>::type` is `int&`.

Comment: I could be wrong but after the reading I've done about this it seems to be more related to the whole 'logical' `const` vs 'physical' `const` issue that crops up in C++. In this case the variable introduced by the compiler with structured bindings is itself `const`, but any pointers or references won't be as they are 'outside' of the object. (I'm attempting to describe the issue where you can modify an object through a pointer in a `const` member function).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) answered the question the question in the comments, let me just cite the relevant part of the standard here, from [dcl.struct.bind]¹:

> Given the type Ti designated by std​::​tuple_­element​::​type, variables are introduced with unique names ri of type “reference to Ti” initialized with the initializer ([dcl.init.ref]), where the reference is an lvalue reference if the initializer is an lvalue and an rvalue reference otherwise.
>   Each vi is the name of an lvalue of type Ti that refers to the object bound to ri; the referenced type is Ti.

Hence in `const auto [z, w] = f();`, you have `const T1` with `T1` being `int` and `const T2` with `T2` being `int&`. As `const` modifies what's on its left, this becomes `int& const` and results in `int&`.

Note that `int& const` becoming `int&` is only possible in template argument substitution, i.e., this won't compile:

```
int n = 42;
int& const doesntWork = n; // Error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'int&'
```

but this does:

```
template <class T> void f(const T t)
{
   ++t;
}

int n = 42;

f<int&>(n);
```

where the identical contraction from `int& const` to `int&` as above takes place.

¹ Thanks to @cpplearner for pointing me to the exact paragraph here.

Answer (score 5):

It would be the reference itself rather than the referenced value that would be const. As references aren't modifiable anyway there is no such thing as a constant reference.